# Bat: how to extract filenames of a command

Tags: batch-file, extract, filenames, command-line-arguments

I am trying to create a script listing the names of the files return by a program.

The program is called ShowFiles.exe and it takes to arguments like this:

```
"ShowFiles opened ..."
```

so argument 1 is "opened" and argument 2 is "..."

The the result looks like this:

```
c:\tmp\test1.txt#0 - add default 
c:\tmp\test2.TXT#1 - edit default
```

What i want is to only get the names of the files.

Like this:

```
test1.txt 

test2.txt
```

Thanks alot for any help.

Comment: What about just giving us data you need to work with? Every solution here will invariably use the `dir` output and tailored for it. Since you can't find a solution on your own I guarantee you won't be able to adapt a solution either.

Comment: @bow: Read what they wrote. The command in question isn't `dir` but something else.

Comment: updated the question, since the comments here do not show linebreaks. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `for /f` to iterate over the command output:

```
for /f %%F in ('ShowFiles ...') do ...
```

This can take some options that control how tokenizing will be done. In your case, the file name apparently stops at a `#`, so the following should split at `#` and only take the first token:

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=#" %%F in ('ShowFiles ...') do (
    echo File name: %%F
    echo File name without path: %%~nxF
)
```

You can then use the file names as shown above for whatever you need. If you just need to output them, then a simple `echo %%F` or `echo %%~nxF` will suffice. More detail on those things can be found in `help for`.